# Who are these members without reputation?

Tags: discussion

I was viewing some questions on `stackoverflow.com`. There was one question asked by one user, this user does not have any reputation point, because all new members have atleast 1 reputation point.

Here is its image [image].

So my question is who are this kind of user? Are they an anonymous user or a regular member?

Here is its asked question [CodeGear Delphi For PHP - Why does readItemIndex() return -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915481/codegear-delphi-for-php-why-readitemindex-returns-1)

Comment: Can you link the question?

Comment: Can you give us a link? It's probably a deleted user. Anonymous things appear under  [Community's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That question was migrated from [webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47117/codegear-delphi-for-php-why-readitemindex-returns-1?noredirect=1). The OP doesn't have an account on SO. That's why there's no rep and no link.

If the OP creates an account on SO, it will turn into a normal account flair with link and rep.

---

Note that deleted accounts as well as disassociated posts will look like that as well.

Comment: He has an account now, so it looks normal.

Comment: Thanks **Mystical** for information..:)

Comment: @Seth Already? It still looks the same to me?

Comment: @Mysticial Whoops. I was looking at the webmasters site no SO. Sorry.